# Dynamic Pointers and Objects

Tags: c++, pointers

I have to write an application to complete an assignment, at school. To do so, we have to create a dynamic array. My question is:

1. If I create a structure containing a dynamic pointer, and copy it, does the memory get copied too?

   For instance:

   ```
   struct SomePointerStruct
   {
        int* p_array;
   }
   ```

   What happens if I copy that structure? Also,
2. Do I need to clean up the original pointer?

Comment: How are you copying it?

Comment: 1. No, you need to follow *the rule of three*. 2. Most likely, yes.

Comment: Your language is sloppy, and this will come to bite you eventually when you start thinking about C++ a bit more. It's not the *pointer* that's dynamic, but the *object to which the pointer points*. Similarly, you don't "clean up pointers"; rather, you clean up *objects* (by means of pointers to the objects).

Comment: @benjymous obj b = a;

Comment: If you want automatic clean-up and well defined copy semantics, assuming you actually want to copy the value of the pointer to a dynamic *variable*, *and* if you can use C++11, use `std::shared_pointer<int>` instead. If you need a dynamic *array*, why not use a `std::vector<int>`? Copying the vector will automatically copy the data it holds as well. You can also just as well use a `shared_ptr` with an actual array, but need to provide a custom deleter that actually calls `delete[]`.

Comment: However, you still would have to implement the deep copy in the copy-ctor of `SomePointerStruct`.

Comment: @thokra There are limitations regarding what we can/can't do (for example, copy constructors are out, since we were not formally taught them yet). Anyway,  I have understood how to do this.

Comment: Well, have you been taught ownership considerations yet? Using a raw pointer as a class member is fishy - you need to think about which object owns what (i.e. who allocates and deallocates stuff) and not just stick some pointer into a class and hope for best. A raw pointer to something is most likely to point to an entity that will outlive the object itself.

Comment: @thokra To be honest,  the pointer is part of an object that lasts the entirety of the execution, and that manipulates an image chosen by ythe user...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40328/discussion-between-mkii-and-thokra)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, objects in c++ are copied byte-by-byte. that means that the pointer will be copied, and you will get two pointers pointing to the same array.

To fix this, you need to implement a `copy constructor` and should also override the `operator=`. Also, you may want to delete this array when you finish, so implement also a `destructor`. That is "the rule of three".

Answer (score 1):

> If I create a structure containing a dynamic pointer, and copy it,
>   does the memory get copied too?

**No.**

Much of the design of the C++ language is dictated by the edict, "You don't pay for what you don't need."  One way this plays out is if you want to deep-copy something, you have to do it yourself.

> Do I need to clean up the original pointer?

In general, yes.

For every `new`, there must be exactly one matching `delete`.  If you instantiate a `SomePointerStruct`, and the construction of that calls `new`, that's one `delete` you need somewhere -- probably in `SomePointerStruct`'s destructor.  If you create a copy of `SomePointerStruct` and the copy deep-copies the original pointer (calling `new`), then that's a second `delete` you need -- again, probably in the destructor.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid repeating the whole chapter named *Memory* from your C++ book, I'll answer with that:

#### Raw pointers shouldn't own memory.

By consequence:

```
struct SomePointerStruct { int x; }
```

is trivially copyable, and:

```
struct SomePointerStruct { std::unique_ptr<int> x; }
```

is noncopyable (but it's moveable). That extends to all of your other types (if they are properly constructed), sans the "trivially", perhaps. The fact that the pointer value would be copied in your original example would of course lead to a lot of problems, but since they can be easily avoided by using what I wrote above, it's kind of off the scope WRT such a simple assignment.

A whole another thing would be a non-owning pointer case, in which  a copied struct would, of course, point to the same region of memory. You lose all the guarantees of the pointer pointing to a valid location, though, so a reference would be preferred.

---

As for creating of a dynamic array, you'd be best off with simply using `std::vector`.